# vb script not working on windows 8

Tags: vbscript

I have a script that I'm using to add watermarks to pdf and worked fine with windows vista and xp

With windows script I'm getting this error :

80070005

This is the script I'm using :

```
    Option Explicit

Const Watermark = "watermark.pdf"
Const Watermark2 = "AAAWatermark.pdf"

Dim objArgs, fname, tfname, fso, pdf

Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments

fname = objArgs(0)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

tfname = fso.GetTempName

Set pdf = WScript.CreateObject("pdfforge.pdf.pdf")

pdf.StampPDFFileWithPDFFile fname, tfname, Watermark, 1, 9999, false, 1, 10 

If fso.FileExists(tfname) Then
fso.DeleteFile(fname)
fso.MoveFile tfname, fname
Else
MsgBox "There was an error adding the Watermark!", vbCritical, AppTitle
End If

Set pdf = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set objArgs = Nothing
```

Any ideal please?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'm a little rough with my Francais, it would appear that you do not have rights to save temporary files in that directory mentioned in the error box or the directory does not exist? You could right click the folder and go to le security tab and add the everyone object and assign write access (or something more secure if you have some other group, etc)

(Edit: The original post had a screenshot in French for added context here)

Comment: Hello 
Thank you 
Yes it's that 
How could I correct it please?
That file doesn't exist 
In Vista it's created automaicly

Comment: run the script as an administrator. if that doesn't do it save to a different directory.

Comment: I have updated my answer. If that fails, you could run as administrator as chilliNUT has suggested Does that help?

Comment: Wonderful 
Worked like a charm ;)